# Array to array of objects

Tags: arrays

I have an array of country such as:

```
country=["Afganistan","Albania","Algeria"]
```

How can I convert this array into array of objects such as:

```
newarray=[
 { key: 'Afghanistan', value: 'Afghanistan', text: 'Afghanistan' },
  { key: 'Albania', value: 'Albania', text: 'Albania' },
  { key: 'Algeria', value: 'Algeria', text: 'Algeria' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
country=["Afganistan","Albania","Algeria"]

let newarray = [];
country.forEach(item => {
  newarray.push({
    key: item,
    value: item,
    text: item
  });
});

console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The method will be:-

```
let newarray = [];
    country.map(item => {
      return newarray.push({ key: item, value: item, text: item })
    })
```